# Detect when column in gtk.treeview is resized

Tags: python, gtk, signals, pygtk, gtktreeview

What signal can I catch to detect when a column changes size in a `gtk.TreeView`? I can't seem to find it in the docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[gtk.TreeViewColumn](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtktreeviewcolumn.html)s aren't widgets so they unfortunately don't have a dedicated signal for size changes. But you can register a callback function that receives "width" [change notifications](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/class-gobject.html#signal-gobject--notify):

```
def onColWidthChange(col, width):
    # Note that "width" is a GParamInt object, not an integer
    ...

col.connect("notify::width", onColWidthChange)
```

In the example, `col` must be a `gtk.TreeViewColumn` object. If you don't initialize the columns in code, you can use [`gtk.TreeView.get_column`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtktreeview.html#method-gtktreeview--get-column) to get these objects.

If you only need notifications when the treeview changes its size, you can use its ["size-allocate"](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#signal-gtkwidget--size-allocate) signal instead.

Comment: see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992602/add-gtk-treeview-columns-to-a-size-group/3999457#3999457) for a hax way to use size-allocate for the columns... but I like this way better =)

Comment: nice, it works. thanks for the links, wouldn't have figured it out w/out them. also change notifications seem pretty useful

Comment: @Claudiu: PyGTK is a nice API but you really need the reference manual to get to know it better. I recommend you to download it so that you can quickly look things up - that actually helped me a lot. The documentation is contained in the [PyGTK sources](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pygtk/).

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I realized I always look at the ref manual actually.. whenever i'm coding i google `gtk.Container` or `gtk.TreeView` and always look at the ref manual pages. it's still easy to miss stuff like change notifications, though.